# Unable to decrypt config property in Spring Cloud config using asymmetric encryption

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to load the decrypted config property from config server but failing with below error:

**2018-08-07 09:58:26.534  WARN 20400 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.c.c.s.e.CipherEnvironmentEncryptor   : Cannot decrypt key: password (class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keys from store: class path resource [server.jks])**

This error happens when server.jks is placed in the classpath. But when placed in C:\drive location it works fine.

**my config server bootstrap.yml:**

```
encrypt:
  key-store:
   # location: file:///C:/keystore/server.jks #using asymmetric encryption
    location: classpath:/server.jks #using asymmetric encryption
    password: springcloudconfig
    alias: testconfigkey
    secret: springcloudconfig       
 # key: springcloudconfig #using symmetric encryption
```

Any idea on what I am missing? Highly appreciate your help!
Spring Boot: 2.0.3
JCE is installed jre/lib location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed the server.jks file is not present in config server project. After placing the file it decrypted the content properly.

Source code is available in Github:

https://github.com/sureshpec04/spring-cloud-config-sample